# Hosting Media Temple reboot pm2

Tags: node.js, nestjs, pm2, mediatemple

In the hosting that I indicate, it happens that every so often I restart my pm2, removing from the list the application developed in Nest.js and the pm2-slack module. What may be causing this reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because of the type of hosting they hired, it must be a vps and not a shared hosting, the latter kills any process that has to do with Node.js